# Diagonalisability…without the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let us consider an $n\times n$ matrix  $A$  defined as follows
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1+a&1&\cdots &1\\
1&1+a&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&1\\
1&\cdots&1&1+a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is diagonalizable without using the characteristic polynomial of $A$. My matrix contains $1+a$ ($a$ is a real number) along the diagonal and $1$ elsewhere. I just noticed that $a$ is   eigenvalue but I don't know how to conclude with that.. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, $A$ is real-symmetric and [all real-symmetric matrices are diagonalizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Comment: of course ! :) thanks.